# read message status by both users in chat system

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, chat

I am creating PHP, ajax based real time chat system, I am facing the problem about status of messages, suppose if user A sends a message to user B, then this message need to show to both users, user A and user B.

I am using status for unread message with 0, to show messages on chat window, but its only appear to one user not the other user, because set interval updating status to 1 after every 2 seconds.

What i thought is to use two different status one for user A and one for user B.
Is this the right way or there could be another way to do it ?

Please provide suggestions.

Comment: why does the sender need to read the message?

Comment: in chat system, both users need to display the messages. i am creating real time chatting system.

Comment: I suspect that you're not the first to create a chat system. How do others handle this aspect of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my old project, I always run a script every three (3) seconds. It submits the last ID of the latest message, and the script checks if there is an ID higher than the latest message ID of the current conversation, if so it will load those messages.

A simplified example is:

```
<div id="message-div">
    <div id="49" class="mes">User 1: What's up?</div>
    <div id="50" class="mes">User 2: Okay. How about you?</div>
    <div id="51" class="mes">User 1: Pretty fine.</div>
</div>
```

My script will run every three (3) seconds, and submit the latest ID using Ajax (*with the example above which is 51*). It will check if there is an ID higher than 51 and then `append()` it to `#message-div`.

Just make sure when you append a new message, it includes the ID of that message.

```
var new-message = '<div id="52" class="mes">User 2: That is good to hear.</div>'; /* THIS COMES FROM AN AJAX REQUEST */
$("#message-div").append(new-message);
```

I did not use a `status` column or whatsoever. What I did for the `read` feature is to have an extra table for storing the date and time when a user read a message.

```
 read_id | message_id | user_id |      read_date
---------+------------+---------+---------------------
    1    |     51     |    2    | 2016-06-03 14:29:30 /* USER 2 READ MESSAGE 51 IN JUNE 3, 2016 AT 2:26 PM */
    2    |     52     |    1    | 2016-06-03 14:30:10
```

Comment: I think your answer is something different but useful,  i need to change my code according to that, but i think it will work without any issues.

Comment: i have to maintain last id, and to keep check that if that incremented in table or not, if incremented then i'll show that, right ?

Comment: @Adas - yes, that is right. It will check your table in your database if there is a higher `message_id`, if so, it will load that/those message/s.

Comment: well i do not want read_date like column because i already using timestamp and will check time from that. But let me change my code and implement your solution, i'll definitely chose your answer.

Comment: @adas - you can have the data type of the `read_date` column to `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: i have tried your answer and IT WORKS, although i had to change my code and faced problem but your logic is also absolutely correct. Really thank you very much for your help. i really appreciate.